# facebook NativeAd in eclipse Could not find class 'com.facebook.ads.internal.view.hscroll.c', referenced from method com.facebook.ads.MediaView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I can get nativeAd in eclipse and show, but add `com.facebook.ads.MediaView` in layout, Start a program then stop running

```
03-17 10:36:56.161: E/dalvikvm(12626): Could not find class 'com.facebook.ads.internal.view.hscroll.c', referenced from method com.facebook.ads.NativeAd.a
03-17 10:36:57.610: E/dalvikvm(12626): Could not find class 'com.facebook.ads.internal.view.hscroll.c', referenced from method com.facebook.ads.MediaView.<init>
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.ads.internal.view.hscroll.c
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.MediaView.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.MediaView.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.b.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.NativeAdView.render(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.NativeAdView.render(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.NativeAd$1$1.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.util.m.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.NativeAd$1.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController.c(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.NativeAd$1.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController$9.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.l.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController.n(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController.d(Unknown Source)
03-17 10:36:57.666: E/AndroidRuntime(12626):    at com.facebook.ads.internal.DisplayAdController$3.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like transitive dependancies are missing. The missing method is actually the missing android RecyclerView support library. You can use the below compile lines to address the issue.

compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.10.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'